# Angularjs ng-include src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem, which happens to be ng-include  not pulling up the file. What is wrong with accessing a property from a link in ng-include? I am wondering if anyone can help me out with this problem.

```js
(function(){
var app = angular.module('AVS', []);
  
  app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
  var tabClasses;
  
  function initTabs() {
    tabClasses = ["","","",""];
  }
  
  $scope.getTabClass = function (tabNum) {
    return tabClasses[tabNum];
  };
  
  $scope.getTabPaneClass = function (tabNum) {
    return "tab-pane " + tabClasses[tabNum];
  };
  
  $scope.setActiveTab = function (tabNum) {
    initTabs();
    tabClasses[tabNum] = "active";
  };
  
  $scope.tab1 = " ";
  $scope.tab2 = "dsadasa ";
  $scope.tab3 = "dsadas ";
  $scope.tab4 = "dsadsa ";
  
  //Initialize 
  initTabs();
  $scope.setActiveTab(1);

  $scope.sutabs = {
    name: ['Life Safety Manager&trade;', 'Life Safety Elements', 'Fire Dampers', 'Fire Extinguishers'],
    number: [1,2,3,4],
    status: ['','','','']
  };

  $scope.lsm = {
    name: ['Life Safety Manager ™', 'Life Safety Elements', 'Fire Dampers', 'Fire Extinguishers'],
    pathname: ['life-safety-manager', 'Life-Safety-Elements', 'Fire-Dampers', 'Fire-Extinguishers'],
    number: [1,2,3,4],
    status: ['','','','']
  };

    $scope.lstabs = {
    name: ['Life Safety Master Plans', 'Evacuation Maps', 'Fire Suppression', 'Fire Alarm Layouts', 'Exit Path Layouts', 'Life Safety Devices', 'Occupancy','Wayfinding'],
    pathname: ['Life-Safety-Master-Plans', 'Evacuation-Maps', 'Fire-Suppression', 'Fire-Alarm-Layouts', 'Exit-Path-Layouts', 'Life-Safety-Devices', 'Occupancy','Wayfinding'],
    number: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    status: ['','','','','','','','']
  };

});
})();
```

```html
  <div class = "row" ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <div class ="col-md-2"> 
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li ng-class="getTabClass({{lsm.number[0]}})" ng-click="setActiveTab({{lsm.number[0]}})" class = "{{lsm.status[0]}}"><a href="#{{lsm.pathname[0]}}" data-toggle="tab">{{lsm.name[0]}}</a></li>
         <li ng-class="getTabClass({{lsm.number[1]}})" ng-click="setActiveTab({{lsm.number[1]}})" class = "{{lsm.status[1]}}"><a href="#{{lsm.pathname[1]}}" data-toggle="tab">{{lsm.name[1]}}</a></li>
         <li ng-class="getTabClass({{lsm.number[2]}})" ng-click="setActiveTab({{lsm.number[2]}})" class = "{{lsm.status[2]}}"><a href="#{{lsm.pathname[2]}}" data-toggle="tab">{{lsm.name[2]}}</a></li>
         <li ng-class="getTabClass({{lsm.number[3]}})" ng-click="setActiveTab({{lsm.number[3]}})" class = "{{lsm.status[3]}}"><a href="#{{lsm.pathname[3]}}" data-toggle="tab">{{lsm.name[3]}}</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-10">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass({{lsm.number[0]}})" id="{{lsm.pathname[0]}}" class="content {{lsm.status[0]}}">  
              <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[0]}}.html'"></div>
           </div>       
          
          <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass({{lsm.number[1]}})" id="{{lsm.pathname[1]}}" class="content {{lsm.status[1]}}">     
              <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[1].html}}'"></div>
          </div>
          
          <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass({{lsm.number[2]}})" id="{{lsm.pathname[2]}}" class="content {{lsm.status[2]}}">     
              <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[2].html}}.html'"></div>
          </div>
          
          <div ng-class="getTabPaneClass({{lsm.number[3]}})" id="{{lsm.pathname[3]}}" class="content {{lsm.status[3]}}">     
            <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[3].html}}.html'"></div>
          </div>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try writing your ng-include like this: `<div ng-include="'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/' + lsm.pathname[3].html + '.html'"></div>`

Comment: I tried using you solution, but I still have the problem, which ng-include pick does not pick up the path.

Comment: As per your object structure, `$scope.lsm.pathname` doesn't have  a property called `html` but you are referencing `{{lsm.pathname[3].html}}` in your `src`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example on

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

it does not use '' it just has

```
ng-include="template.url"
```

Now, I do understand that you need to wrap with a '' for a string. But template.url is from the scope. Maybe you cannot mix and match with static and scope with ng-include.

Sorry if this does not help, I had a play with the plunk on the link above and could not get it to mix and match. So make your scope var have the full url

Comment: Actually the problem with his code is not related to matching static and scope properties. Remember in angular expression `{{}}` you can do string concatenation and evaluate (some) javascript.

Comment: thanks, my wife was telling me to come for tea so I didn't have time todo a proper test :) tea was good though :)

Answer (score 0):

In this

```
 <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[3].html}}.html'"></div>
```

In the `src`, you have `{{lsm.pathname[3]` which will actually return you string. But you've also added `{{lsm.pathname[3].html` that means it will start looking for `html` property inside `pathname[3]`.

So it must be like:

```
 <div ng-include src = "'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/{{lsm.pathname[3]}}.html'"></div>
```

Which can be better represented as:

```
   <div ng-include src = "{{'disciplinedrawings/life-safety-manager/'+lsm.pathname[3]+'.html'}}"></div>
```